Creating a dataframe from vectors
I have the following data and need to convert it into a dataframe so it can then be analysed through ANOVA:

I have tried to load the data frame but can only work out how to do one of the two vectors per developer/time as shown below:

developer <- rep(1:3, each=2)  

10 <- c(0, 5, 4, 7, 7, 8) 
14 <- c(1, 4, 6, 7, 10, 8) 
18 <- c(2, 4, 9, 8, 12, 9) 

development_data <- data.frame(Developer=developer, `10`=10, `14`=14, `18`=18)
print(development_data)

How can I ensure all of the vectors are added and not only that but ensure the data can be analysed using r as collective vectors instead of separate values?

Here an example of how you could make this data in a data.frame in a long format
code
developer_strength <- rep(1,12)
development_time <- rep(c(10,14,18),each = 4)
value <- c(0,2,5,4,1,3,4,2,2,5,4,6)

data.frame(developer_strength,development_time,value)

result
   developer_strength development_time value
1                   1               10     0
2                   1               10     2
3                   1               10     5
4                   1               10     4
5                   1               14     1
6                   1               14     3
7                   1               14     4
8                   1               14     2
9                   1               18     2
10                  1               18     5
11                  1               18     4
12                  1               18     6

